# JQuery event for only one element of a specific class

Tags: jquery, class, events, element

I'm new to jQuery and can't seem to understand how to solve this problem on my own.

The issue is that when I press on one element (div) with the same class, all others also open.
Here's a gif that shows the problem. - https://gyazo.com/8315d69878d7e5efb5a699798343b278

```html
      <div class="middle-side">
        <div class="items"><img src="img/services/1.jpg" alt="">
          <div class="blue-img"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="items"><img src="img/services/2.jpg" alt="">
          <div class="blue-img"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="items"><img src="img/services/3.jpg" alt="">
          <div class="blue-img"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

```
$(document).ready(() => {
    $('.items').on('click', () => {
        $('.blue-img').slideToggle();
    })
})
```

Comment: Instead of using classes you might want to use id's to refer individual elements

Comment: @Mike in cases like the OPs that would be anti-pattern

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Ahh i see. your solution is much better

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is because you're selecting all `.blue-img` elements within the click handler.

To fix this use the `this` keyword to refer to the clicked `.items` element, then `find()` the `div` within it. Try this:

```js
$(document).ready(() => {
  $('.items').on('click', (e) => {
    $(e.target).find('.blue-img').slideToggle();
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="middle-side">
  <div class="items">
    A
    <img src="img/services/1.jpg" alt="">
    <div class="blue-img">Blue-img A</div>
  </div>
  <div class="items">
    B
    <img src="img/services/2.jpg" alt="">
    <div class="blue-img">Blue-img B</div>
  </div>
  <div class="items">
    C
    <img src="img/services/3.jpg" alt="">
    <div class="blue-img">Blue-img C</div>
  </div>
</div>
```